# ng-click does not work for linking to another view

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to link to a different page/view via ng-click and a function inside my controller. I don't do it with href because later it should be a right-click-event. But my code doesn't work. I've tried very much, and searched alot of pages but I can't find any solution. Thanks for your help :)

**game.html**

```html
<div class="container" ng-controller="MainController">
 <div class="handcards" ng-repeat="card in stdCards">
     <a ng-click="goToCardDetail()" href="">{{ card.name }}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**MainController.js**

```js
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'stdcards', '$location', function($scope, stdcards, $location) {
 stdcards.success(function(data) {
  $scope.stdCards = data;
 });
 
 $scope.goToCardDetail = function() {
  $location.path('#/cards/0');
 };
}]);
```

**app.js**

```js
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
   controller: 'MainController',
   templateUrl: 'templates/game.html'
  })
  .when('/cards/:id', {
   controller: 'CardController',
   templateUrl: 'templates/card.html'
  })
  .otherwise({
   redirectTo: '/'
  });
});
```

Comment: Consider using ngHref instead of ngClick: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to include the `#` when you are calling `$location.path()`. So it should just be

```
$location.path('/cards/0');
```

Comment: Thanks :) You saved my night and the following days ;)